# dart/flutter: assign saturation of HSLColor after creation

Tags: flutter, dart, colors, hsl

### Goal

I'd love to do the following

1. Convert `Color` to `HSLColor`;
2. Customize the saturation of the color;
3. Finally convert the `HSLColor` back to `Color`.

### Problems

But it turns out that the HSLColor's properties including saturation are final.
Then how do I modify the HSL color space then?

Comment: `hsl.withSaturation(...).toColor()`